# Save value of text on radiobutton change (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I've got 8 radio buttons, and when the 8th is selected, a textfield appears in which you can type something. Now if something is typed in the textfield and another radio button gets checked, I want to save the text but empty the textfield and when they re-check the 8th again, the textfield fills with the previously inputted data.

I've tried the following:

```
referenceRadio.change(function() {
    otherTextValue = otherText.val();
    console.log(otherTextValue);
    if($(this).val()=="8") {
        otherText.show().prop('required', true);
        otherText.val(otherTextValue);
    } else {
        otherText.val('');
        otherText.hide().prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

If any other information is required, please ask, new to this.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Managed to get it working with the following code:

```
referenceRadio.change(function() {
    console.log(otherText.val());
    if($(this).val()=="8") {
        otherText.show().prop('required', true);
        otherText.val(otherTextValue);
    } else {
        if(otherText.val() != '') {
            /* Only retrieve otherText.val when its not empty */
            otherTextValue = otherText.val();
        }
        otherText.val('');
        otherText.hide().prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it through:

1. A radio button other than 8 is currently selected.
2. Now you click 8, and this happens:

   ```
   otherTextValue = otherText.val();
   ```
3. Now `otherTextValue` is `""`.

It should work if you put it in the `else` clause, before you empty the text field, and you should make that clause an `else if`, so that it is only executed if 8 was selected last:

```
referenceRadio.change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "8") {
        otherText.show().prop('required', true);
        otherText.val(otherTextValue);
    } else if(lastRadioValue == "8") {
        otherTextValue = otherText.val();
        otherText.val('');
        otherText.hide().prop('required', false);
    }
    lastRadioValue = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but this works only once, if I go from the 8th, to the 5th, the 6th and back to the 8th for example, it loses it's value.

Comment: Never mind, your answer helped a lot, will update my question with the working answer and accept your answer asap. Thanks

Comment: Damn, I missed that. Updated my answer. I think your solution actually has a bug, try this: Click 8, enter some text, click 5, click 8, remove the text, click 5, click 8 - the text is there again, right?

Comment: Don't see a bug? The text is supposed to show when I click 8. Even if it was emptied before. My requirement was that if 8 was not selected, it wouldn't save any text to the database, just an empty record. Once 8 is selected, I want it to contain something.

Comment: I think a user who decided to delete the text from the text field would not expect or want it to reappear by changing the radio selection forth and back, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: This function is only for back-end editing. So merely for myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for 8th radio, you can try this :

```
var msgText='';
referenceRadio.change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="8") {
        otherText.val(msgText).show().prop('required', true);
    } else {
        msgText=otherText.val();
        otherText.val('').hide().prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution overrides the otherText after selecting a couple of radio buttons after the 8th.